# Openshift communication Services

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, microservices

In Openshift I have two services that I need to communicate with each other, I was wondering if you know a way to do that without exposing both microservices.

Example:

```
(via public endpoint)    (exposed)           (non public service)
User-request ----------> Service A ----------> Service B
```

Service A needs to request an endpoint on service B and for that, I am using DNS but to do that I need to expose Service B.

There is any way to do this scenario without exposing service B?

To expose Service A I run the command: "oc expose service/ServiceA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a Service of type `ClusterIP` you can directly talk to that service using its DNS name and that Service is available within the cluster. The default DNS name for these services is `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`.

When using `oc expose service` you are creating a "Route" that will then make a Service available externally (not what you want in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I changed the URL used to make a rest request to **http://serviceB.demo.svc.cluster.local** as you mention and I got problems with access to the host

"Unable to invoke request: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)"

and 
"Retrying request to {}->http://reservation-service.demo.svc.cluster.local:80"

Comment: Please add your service definition (`oc get svc <name> -o yaml`) and the relevant endpoints (`oc get endpoint <name> -o yaml`) to your question, which could help in debugging. Also, are you using NetworkPolicies that block this traffic?

Comment: I solve the problem by restarting my local openshift, I don't know why but this restart fixed the problem..

I am using network policy to restrict the access and I am using the ...svc.cluster.local:8080 to comunicate with other microservices


Thanks for your help guys!